# How to connect to TFS through VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, tfs

Really need a assistance here. Google didn't help me much. I found this is somewhat plain solution.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/183317/Update-TFS-WorkItem-from-Microsoft-Access-using-VB

But is it possible to connect the TFS without the help of dot net visual studio. Something like adding the reference and using those in code.

Comment: Looking at the link you provided, it looks like the API is managed code, so your answer would be "nope" :-(

Comment: please add some relevant info on what the link is about, not only to provide a preview of it but also to prevent the question to become useless if the link breaks or changes

Comment: you should probably add some info about what it is you're trying to achieve, there may well be something that already does what you want to do without resorting to excel macros

Comment: The main this that I am trying to achieve is to pull the data from TFS using macro

Answer (score 2):

The TFS Client Object Model is not exposed to COM and there is no way to call the .NET objects directly from VBA without a COM wrapper.

If you're connecting to TFS 2015 or Visual Studio Online, [you may be able to use the REST API's by directly invoking the REST calls](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/overview).

Not sure why you would not just use VSTO in Access, which allows you to use C# or VB.NET for your add-in.